# Why does a call to fread set my file pointer to null?

Tags: c, file-io, fread

I have a file pointer which is valid before calling fread, and NULL after, and I'd really like to know why.

Here is the relevant code:

```
244 // open the file for reading
245 clo->heap_file = open_file(heap_path, "rb");

443 // allocate memory to read a page from the file
444 file_page = safe_malloc(clo->page_size);

446 // read a page in to memory from the file
447 read_page(file_page, clo);

void *
safe_malloc(size_t size)
{
   void * mem_block = NULL;

   mem_block = calloc(1, size);

   if (mem_block == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: safe_malloc() failed to allocate memory.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   return (mem_block);
}

FILE *
open_file(char * file_name, char * file_mode)
{
    FILE * fp;
    char * err_msg = ((strcmp(file_mode, "rb") == 0)
          ? "File not found"
          : "File could not be created");

    fp = fopen(file_name, file_mode);

    /* Print an appropriate error message and exit if open failed */
    if (fp == NULL) {
       fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", err_msg, file_name);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return fp;
}

void
read_page(clo_t * clo, void * file_page)
{
   fread(file_page, sizeof(size_t), clo->page_size, clo->heap_file);

   if (ferror(clo->heap_file)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: could not read heap file!\n\n");
      free(file_page);
      destroy_clo(clo);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
}
```

GDB trace:

```
(gdb) p clo->heap_file
$1 = (FILE *) 0x603070
(gdb) s
read_page (clo=0x6032d0, file_page=0x603010) at dbquery.c:331
331        fread(file_page, clo->page_size, 1, clo->heap_file);
(gdb) s
333        if (ferror(clo->heap_file)) {
(gdb) p clo->heap_file
$2 = (FILE *) 0x0
```

And Valgrind doesn't indicate that I'm doing anything wrong either...

I'd like to think that I'm pretty good at handling return values, making sure pointers are valid, etc, but this one has me stumped.

Comment: Are you sure about `fread(file_page, sizeof(size_t),...`?

Comment: One line 447 you are passing in the parameters to `read_page` in the wrong order

Comment: If valgrind isn't picking anything up here, then valgrind is faulty. Which OS are you using?

Comment: What is address of `clo->heap_file` as you have shown in gdb output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 issues,

1. Change `447 read_page(file_page, clo);` to `447 read_page(clo, file_page);` as per definition of the function.
2. Change `fread(file_page, sizeof(size_t), clo->page_size, clo->heap_file);` to `fread(file_page, 1, clo->page_size, clo->heap_file);`. Do not use `sizeof(size_t)` as 2nd parameter to `fread`.

   Your call will try to read `sizeof(size_t) * clo->page_size` bytes which is more than you have allocated for `file_page` that is `1 * clo->page_size`.

Comment: It's always something so simple.  I can't believe I didn't see that, but I also don't understand why the compiler didn't complain about the mismatched arguments to read_page.  Thanks.